# Calculate Probabilities of multiple bit-wise operations

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

A bit wise operation is written as $(A\&B)$ where $X$ can be replaced with either $0$, $1$, $y$, $Y$ ($y$ is complement of $Y$, and vice versa).

"$A and B$" can be replaced with [and ($\&$),or( $|$ ),xor($\wedge$)] operators.

In a simple expression like $(A \& B)$ for "and" function:

probability for $0$ is $\frac{9}{16}$;

probability for $1$ is $\frac{1}{16}$;

probability for $y$ is $\frac{3}{16}$;

probability for $Y$ is $\frac{3}{16}$;

How would I proceed to solve multiple expressions, for example: $(((A \& B) \wedge C) | D)$?

While A,B,C,D can be replaced with 0,1,a or A

Comment: I think you mean to ask about (((A & B) ^ C) | D)

Comment: I edited the question... any suggestions as to how i should proceed to calculate this?

Answer (score 1):

This question is an active question in the ongoing competitive programming competition on CodeChef. Source: [here](https://www.codechef.com/APRIL20B/problems/REBIT)

If you've asked this question to copy it over there, this would be considered plagiarism/cheating according to Codechef Code of Conduct.

If not, please wait till the comeptition is over (April 13th 2020) to get your question answered.